# Intellij: javafx application icon

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

How to set default application bootstrapper(?) icon, builded by Intellij?

[image]

Comment: Is the .ico file not being picked up as the icon? What happens if you change that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to change the icon of an exe file.
First if you do not have the ico  file get the picture you want from google and then convert it into an ico file.        using: "http://convertico.com/"

I googled how to modify an exe file and actually modified the icon of an exe file from this link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/

read the above link and go through the steps for full solution.
it uses resource hacker which seems pretty well known and used.

but...

if you get access denied:
"I ended up changing googlechrome icon but was receiving access denied. So i saved as googlechrome1 on my desktop. renamed to googlechrome.exe (on Desktop).
next, I went to the location of googlechrome.exe - in program files deleted googlechrome.exe and then moved the clone from desktop to that location."

Comment: if question was changing icon for exe file additional support here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673203/add-icon-to-existing-exe-file-from-the-command-line